# Add another data to the firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

In my web app, I want to create a classroom and add the data to my firebase database.

```
var fbclass = firebase.database().ref().child('Classes');

function classcreation(q) {

  var usuid = generateId();
  var myClasses={};

  myClasses.TheClass = document.getElementById('classroomName').value;
  myClasses.Teacher = user.displayName;
  myClasses.TeacherEmail = user.email;
  myClasses.ClassID = usuid;
  fbclass.child(user.uid).set(myClasses);
  }

function generateId(){
return 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'.replace(/[x]/g, function(){
  return (Math.random() * 9 | 0 ).toString();
  })
}
```

After submitting the button it will then store the data to the firebase

[image]

but the problem is, if I create another classroom with the same user, it will just update the TheClass[classname] and not create another classroom.

[image]

What's wrong with my code? What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `set()` method you are writing the data at the `fbclass.child(user.uid)` location (i.e. reference), see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#set).

Since your location is based on `user.uid` you are using the same location again and again for a given user: hence the overwrite you encounter (since `set()` "overwrites any data at this location and all child locations").

You should generate a unique key, each time you write a new classroom for the same user. For that you should use the `push()` method ([doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push)) which "generates a new child location using a unique key", as follows:

```
var newClassroomRef = fbclass.child(user.uid).push(
  {
    'Class_Id': '....',
    'Teacher': '....'
  }
);
```

The following would also work:

```
var newClassroomRef = fbclass.child(user.uid).push();
newClassroomRef.set({
  'Class_Id': '....',
  'Teacher': '....'
});
```

Note that this will create an extra level in your node tree, under the `user.uid` node;

```
- Classes
    - yo9HQ.......  <- user.uid
        - 6trQEd.......  <- classroom uid
           - Teacher: .....
           - .....: .....
        - PKH6fd.......  <- classroom uid
           - Teacher: .....
           - .....: .....
```

Comment: How do I retrieve the data? 
  var getClassInfo = firebase.database().ref().child('Classes'+ user.uid + '/');
  getClassInfo.on('value', gotData,errData);

  function gotData(data) {
    //console.log(data.val());
    var Classes = data.val()
    var keys = Object.keys(Classes);
    console.log(keys);
    for (var i =0; i < keys.length; i ++){
      var k = keys[i];
      var TheClass = Classes[k].TheClass;
      console.log(TheClass);
    }
  }

  function errData(err) {
    console.log('Error!');
    console.log(err);

  }

Comment: I would suggest you create a new question as this is different from your initial question and secondly it is really not easy to read code within comments!!

Comment: Okay, I will put the link here

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428450/how-can-i-get-the-reference-of-the-push-in-firebase-database) @Renaud Tarnec here's the link ;)

Comment: I was about to reply to your answer but it seems that it was deleted

Comment: It should be ok now

Comment: Are u still there, mr. renaud?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few pointers that'll be handy.

1. All keys are unique. You cannot have two indices of same key. Having said that, you are assigning a key as `user.uid` which will always be the same. Essentially, you are updating the value present at the key.
2. Here, I am assuming you want to make keys based on the uid of the user using the database. So, using `set` will only store your data, which means if you give it a new uid, it'll wipe off the data in your `Classes` key and set it with your new `user.uid` key that you have provided. If you want to append the new key, you'll need ti use the method `update` instead of set. It'll update your `Classes` key with the new `user.uid` key which means that you'll appending data to your `Classes` object. 
   Something on the lines of -   `fbclass.child(newUserID).update(myClasses);`

Hope it helps :))