# How can I get the reference of the push() in firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve the data from my firebase database.

[image]

The one that was highlighted in the IMG 1 is the user uid and below it was the value from the push().

This is my code to retrieve the data

```
var getClassInfo = firebase.database().ref().child('Classes'+ user.uid + 
'/');
 getClassInfo.on('value', gotData,errData);

function gotData(data) {
//console.log(data.val());
var Classes = data.val()
var keys = Object.keys(Classes);
console.log(keys);


for (var i =0; i < keys.length; i ++){
  var k = keys[i];
  var TheClass = Classes[k].TheClass;
  console.log(TheClass);
  }
  }

function errData(err) {
console.log('Error!');
console.log(err);

 }
```

How do I ref() the value of the push()?

```
var getClassInfo = firebase.database().ref().child('Classes'+ user.uid + 
[push()]);
```

How do I retrieve all classroom name from a particular user [TheClass]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of the classroom created via the push, do as follows, where `classId` is the key created by the push (e.g. LMpv.....)

```
    firebase.database().ref('Classes/' + user.uid + '/' + classId).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {           
        console.log(snapshot.val().TheClass);
        // ....
    });
```

---

To retrieve all the classroom `name`s for a particular `user`, do as follows:

```
var userRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Classes' + '/' + user.uid);
userRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var childData = childSnapshot.val();
    var classroomName = childData.TheClass
  });
});
```

By using the `once()` method, you read once the values from the database, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once

If you want to use the `on()` method (as you do in your question) and continuously listen to the `user` node and detect when new classrooms are added, do as follows:

```
var userRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Classes' + '/' + user.uid);
userRef.on('child_added', function(data) {
  console.log(data.val().TheClass);
});
```

See the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on).

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr. Renaud. One last thing, how do I put it on a list?Let say, I want to show all the classrooms of a particular user on a list in my main.html

Comment: You populate your list in the snapshot.forEach() method. See the following for indications on how to do that: https://www.vitoshacademy.com/javascript-create-ul-and-li-elements-with-js-with-chained-function/, https://getbutterfly.com/generate-html-list-from-javascript-array/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128700/create-a-ul-and-fill-it-based-on-a-passed-array

Comment: Done!! It says it was recorded

Comment: Mr. Renaud, I successfully populated my list. The user can now view all the classrooms he/she created. But I have some questions, I hope that you will still help me. I am very sorry for all the trouble.

Comment: @DodongAdvices I would suggest that you create a new question. Don't worry there is no "trouble" at all to help fellow programmers on Stack Overflow :-)  We all need some help one day or the other to learn new techniques!

Comment: I'm considering myself very lucky because you're here, Mr. Renaud. #NoHomo... here's the to my  [Link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443774/how-to-add-links-in-every-data-of-my-list) to my new question