# How to add links in every data of my list?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

After creating new classroom, the data will then be send to a list as shown on the
IMG 1:
[image: IMG 1]

Now, how do I add/make (a) link/s into every classroom so that whenever I click it it will redirect me to a page and show me their specific data like ClassroomID, students, etc.

here's the code:

```
//retrieving

var userRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Classes' + '/' + user.uid);
userRef.on('child_added', function(data) {

    var roomNames = data.val().TheClass;

    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    document.getElementById('myList').appendChild(ul);

    var li = document.createElement('li');
    ul.appendChild(li);
    Object.keys(roomNames).forEach(function(key) {
        li.innerHTML += roomNames[key];

    });


});

//adding

function classcreation(q) {
    var checkcn = document.getElementById('classroomName').value;
    if (checkcn == "" && checkcn == null) {
        alert("Empty Class Name!!");
    } else {
        var usuid = generateId();
        var myClasses = {};
        myClasses.TheClass = document.getElementById('classroomName').value;
        myClasses.Teacher = user.displayName;
        myClasses.TeacherID = user.uid;
        myClasses.ClassID = usuid;
        fbclass.child(user.uid).push().set(myClasses);

    }
}
```

Comment: What's your code?

Comment: Images are not helpful, code is.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Are you using any javascript framework?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to add the code. You can view it now ;)

Comment: so create a link and append it to the li....

Comment: How do I create a link?

Comment: Same way you created the li and the ul in your code!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify like this:

```
<li><a href="#redirect">BSIT</a></li>
<li><a href="#redirect">BSCS</a></li>
<li><a href="#redirect">BSCE</a></li>
```

Here, redirect is the partial html where you will land after click on list item text..

I hope this will be helpful to you

Comment: After li creation you can create a tag  var a = document.createElement('a');
li.appendChild(a);   append inner html to a tag.. I will modify my answer so it will be helpful

Comment: What I mean is, make or add a link on it so that I can click it

Comment: @Dodong yes.. The <a> tag defines a hyperlink, which is used to link from one page to another. The most important attribute of the <a> element is the href attribute, which indicates the link's destination. By default, links will appear as follows in all browsers